# Android ksoap2 with https

Tags: android

I want to implement `ksoap2` web service using HTTPS(HTTP over SSL). I searched a lot over net but didn't find any tutorial for this. However, I found a tutorial for HTTP which works fine.

Has anyone worked on something similar ? Any code provided will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

use the latest release with the KeepAliveHttpsTransportSE. All other stuff is the same.

Make sure your server certificate is configured properly. If you have problems you can deactivate it for certain version.

See my gist at https://gist.github.com/908048